# How to change format of list in which it is being printed

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pokeapi

I have a list:

```
import pokebase as pb
p1 = pb.pokemon('charmander')
for stat in p1.stats:
    result = ['''{}
{}'''.format(stat.stat.name, stat.base_stat)
        for stat in p1.stats]
print(f'''
{result[0]}
{result[1]}
{result[2]}
{result[3]}
{result[4]}
{result[5]}
''')
```

It prints the list like this:

```
hp
39
attack
52
defense
43
special-attack
60
special-defense
50
speed
65
```

But I want the list to be printed like this:

```
hp                attack             defense    
39                52                 43 
special-attack    special-defense    speed        
60                50                 65
```

How can I do that?
actually I dont know about .format() function properly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this. Here's one way:-

```
import pokebase as pb
p1 = pb.pokemon('charmander')
R = []
mlen = 0
pad = 2
for v in p1.stats:
    n = v.stat.name
    mlen = max(mlen, len(n) + pad)
    R.append((n, v.base_stat))
t = 0
for i in range(len(R) * 2):
    if i != 0 and i % 3 == 0:
        t ^= 1
        print()
    print(f'{R[i//2][t]: <{mlen}}', end='')
print()
```

Comment: sir there's something wrong with your code it have you checked it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code providing you're using an up-to-date version of Python. If you're on 2.x then I agree, it won't work because of the f-string

Answer (score 1):

Left align with 20 char space

If you need right alignment use >20

You can ignore the numpy engineering there. I did it for convenience. But main idea to use <20 left formatting

```py
result = ['hp','39','attack','52','defense','43','special-attack','60','special-defense','50','speed','65']
# for convenience to not complicate code for explanation
r = np.array(result)
r.shape = (2, 3, 2)
# array([[['hp', '39'],
#         ['attack', '52'],
#         ['defense', '43']],

#        [['special-attack', '60'],
#         ['special-defense', '50'],
#         ['speed', '65']]], dtype='<U15')


row_format ="{:<20}" * 3
for row in r:
    # here row1 is column of [hp, attack defense], look above comment for visualization
    row1 = row[:, 0]
    # row2 is column of values
    row2 = row[:, 1]
    # *row1 is unwrapping list row1 into arguments for format function
    print(row_format.format(*row1))
    print(row_format.format(*row2))
```

```
hp                  attack              defense             
39                  52                  43                  
special-attack      special-defense     speed               
60                  50                  65
```

Comment: it gives me ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6 into shape (2,3,2)

Comment: I think your size of result is 6, the one I used has size 12, look at result value I used it has 2 * 3 * 2 entries. Change your code so that array result looks like above

Answer (score 1):

Working directly with the data you have in `result`, you can just pad spaces on the right to force your columns to align.

```
result = [
    'hp', '39', 
    'attack', '52', 
    'defense', '43', 
    'special-attack', '60', 
    'special-defense', '50', 
    'speed', '65'
]
stat_line = ''
val_line = ''
for i, (stat, value) in enumerate(zip(result[::2], result[1::2]), 1):
    if i % 3:
        stat_line += f'{stat:<20}'
        val_line += f'{value:<20}'
    else:
        print(stat_line + stat)
        print(val_line, value)
        stat_line = ''
        val_line = ''
```

A break down of what is happening:

`[::2]` slices your `list` and iterates over every other character.

`[1::2]` does the same except it starts at the second element.

`zip()` allows you to iterate over 2 iterables at once. So effectively, you are getting `('hp', 39)`, `('attack', 52)`, etc.. unpacked into `(stat, value)` as you iterate.

`enumerate(iterable, 1)` gives you an increasing integer starting at 1 as you iterate. You can use this to determine when you are at your third element.(`i % 3`) This is used to `print` the current 3 stats and values and clear out the strings so you can continue adding onto them.

From there, it's just simply using `f'{stat:<20}'` to right pad 20 spaces onto the string value to force them to all have the same length and therefore align.

The final result:

```
hp                  attack              defense
39                  52                   43
special-attack      special-defense     speed
60                  50                   65
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def print_in_my_way(x):
    global result
    m = max(result, key=lambda x: len(str(x)))
    m = len(str(m)) 
    # m += 5 If u need more space 
    def do(subx):
        print(*[f'{i:<{m}}' for i in subx])
    do(x[::2])
    do(x[1::2])

result = ['hp',
39,
'attack',
52,
'defense',
43,
'special-attack',
60,
'special-defense',
50,
'speed',
65]
n = len(result)//2
print_in_my_way(result[:n])
print_in_my_way(result[n:])
```

Using the value of n, you may adjust how many values you need in your first row & so on!